# Best way to integrate php and Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a .php file where I have some script running to display "cards". I have 6 cards showing and the text being displayed is hard coded.  I am ready to start pulling from my database and remove my hard code sections.

```
        //Set number of cards to show
    multiplyNode(document.querySelector('.card_content'), 6, true);  

    var authors = ["Margaret", "Lucy", "Odessa", "Shifty", "Saggy", "Lady"];
    var BookNumbers = [2563, 8547, 5896, 4157, 5823, 7963];
        $(function(){box_title

        //$(".card_content").clone(true).appendTo(".main_card_shell");
        $('.box_title').each(function (i) { 
            $(this).html("<div class='card_name'>" + authors[i] + "</div>" +
            "<div class='card_number'>" + BookNumbers[i] +  "</div>" +
                            "<div class='tag_row'>" +
                                "<div class='sample_tag sample_tag4'></div>" +
                                "<div class='sample_tag sample_tag3'></div>" +
                            "</div>");

        });

    })
```

I know I can pull the data I want from my database via:

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT `Author`, `Book_Num` FROM `Authors`");
```

but how is the best way to get my $result to replace my hard coded authors and BookNumbers array?

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the results to build a php array with the same structure as your javascript arrays, then use `json_encode` to convert it to a javascript array format.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
<?php
$result = $conn->query("SELECT `Author`, `Book_Num` FROM `Authors`");
// loop through the results to build the php arrays
while($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
    // set the author and book number to array with numeric key
    $authors[] = $row['Author'];
    $BookNumbers[] = $row['Book_Num'];
}
// use json_encode to convert the php array to an javascript array
echo "var authors = ".json_encode($authors).";\n";
echo "var BookNumbers = ".json_encode($BookNumbers).";\n";
?>
</script>
```

A comment: unless you need interactivity you could build the html with php without using jquery

Comment: Thanks for the help.  If I wanted to print out what I was storing, could I just put a echo $row['Author']; in the loop?  Currently I am not getting errors but nothing is dumping out.  I have my code set just like you have it.

Comment: $result will return false on failure so you can add error checking. I'm assuming you have successfully connected to the database to run the query and there are records in the table

Comment: So I built my php array as you described above but when I try an incorporate it into my javascript function, I can't get it to work

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? What does the php output? What errors?